# Gender (and other additional claims) missing from OAuthCreatingTicketContext

Tags: c#, google-oauth

I have my Google Authentication provider configured like this:

```
.AddGoogle(options =>
                {
                    options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo";

                    options.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read");
                    options.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read");
                    options.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read");
                    options.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read");
                    options.ClaimActions.MapAll();

                    options.SignInScheme = "google.identity";

                    options.ClientId = "REDACTED";
                    options.ClientSecret = "REDACTED";

                    options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = (context) =>
                    {
                        var gender = context.User.GetProperty("gender").GetString(); // Throws KeyNotFoundException
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
                });
```

But attempting to get the gender property throws a KeyNotFoundException.

I have checked with my test application and it does request the correct scopes

[image]

It's important to note that I am debugging this locally (via HTTPS)

Comment: Do you get the others without problem?

Comment: I do not @Fildor - I just get the standard claims e.g. email, locale etc.  I would expect these additional claims to also be in the collection.

Comment: Being not familiar with the google api, my first guess would be the property name ...

Comment: Have you debugged the `context.User` object? Can you spot the property keys? Could it be a mispelling?

Comment: Yeah the object returned looks like this:

{
  "id": "106649806655040415125",
  "email": "REDACTED",
  "verified_email": true,
  "name": "REDACTED",
  "given_name": "REDACTED",
  "family_name": "REDACTED",
  "picture": "REDACTED",
  "locale": "en-GB"
} - So it looks like Google isn't sending me them - even though I am requesting them.

Answer (score 1):

The claims returned by the Google Authorization server are extremely limited.  You will not get things like gender info from that.  In order to get the gender for a user serval things need to happen.  First the user needs to have it set. Under their [profile](https://myaccount.google.com/gender?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmyaccount.google.com%2Fprofile)

[image]

Then you need to authorize the user with the following scopes yes both.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

Only then will you see the gender information for the user.

## [Example](https://www.daimto.com/asp-net-core-3-and-google-login/)

Then you just need to make a request to the [people api](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22resourceName%22%3A%22people%2Fme%22%2C%22personFields%22%3A%22genders%22%7D) to get the users profile information.

```
[GoogleScopedAuthorize(PeopleServiceService.ScopeConstants.UserinfoProfile,PeopleServiceService.ScopeConstants.UserGenderRead)]
 public async Task UserProfile([FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth)
        {
            var cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();
            var service = new PeopleServiceService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = cred
                });
            

            var request = service.People.Get("people/me");
            request.PersonFields = "gender";
            var person = await request.ExecuteAsync();

            return View(person);
        }
```

Comment: That seems weird - Why would you give consent to share your birthday etc but then have to make that information publicly accessible?